# Check the existence of second order partial derivatives at $(0,0)$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Check the existence of second order partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ of
$$
f(x,y) = \left\{
   \begin{array}{rl}
    y^3 \cos(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2}), & \text{if }  (x,y) \neq 0 \\
     0, & \text{if } (x,y) = 0.
   \end{array}\right.
$$

$f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, but it does not imply existence of even the first order partial derivative.

How should I approach this problem? By definition?

$$
f_{xy}(0,0) = \lim \limits_{y \to 0} \frac{f_x(0,y)-f_x(0,0)}{y} =  \lim \limits_{y \to 0} \frac{0}{y} = 0, 
$$

because:
$f_x(0,0)=0$

$f_x(x,y) = \frac{2xy^3 \sin(\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2})}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}$

$f_x(0,y) = 0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Seems correct.  But you should write explicitly that the formula for $f_x(x,y)$ holds only for $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$.  And notice that you have to find (by definition) the derivatives $f_{yx}(0,0)$ and $f_{yy}(0,0)$ (besides $f_{xx}(0,0)$, which is trivially equal to zero, since $f(x,0)=0$ for any $x$).